# Regex extraction of a specific pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a string of following format. I have three scenarios which follows as:

**Scenario 1:**

```
"\\hjsschjsn\Bunong.PU2.PV/-56Noogg.BSC";
```

The extraction should be until **".BSC"** , **".BSC"** will be there in the original string always. Also **"\"**  and **"\"** will be there but the text will change.

I have to omit the middle part , my output should be :

```
"\\hjsschjsn\-56Noogg.BSC";
```

**Scenarion 2:**

```
"\\adajsschjsn\Bcscx.sdjhs\AHHJogg.BSC";
```

The output should be :

```
"\\adajsschjsn\AHHJogg.BSC";
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
"aasjkankn\\adajsschjsn\Bcscx.sdjhs\AHHJogg.BSC\djkhakdjhjkj";
```

output should be:

```
"\\adajsschjsn\AHHJogg.BSC";
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
 string text = "\\\\hjsschjsn\Bunong.PU2.PV/-56Noogg.BSC";
 //Note: I have given \\\\ instead of \\ because of string literal to be accomadated in a string
 Match pattern = Regex.Match(text, @"\\\\[\w]+\\/[\w*]+.BSC");
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your first scenario or is the '/' forward slash intentional?

Comment: @twhetsto: '/' forward slash is intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following mask:

```
.*(\\\\[^\\]*\\)([^\\\/]+)[\\\/](.*?\.BSC).*
```

Replace it with $1$3

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*(\\\\[^\\]*\\)([^\\\/]+)[\\\/](.*?\.BSC).*");
string input = @"\\hjsschjsn\Bunong.PU2.PV/-56Noogg.BSC";
string output = reg.Replace(input, "$1$3");
```

See example [here](https://regex101.com/r/8CVILw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Match pattern1 = Regex.Match(text, @"\\\\\w+\\");

Match pattern2 = Regex.Match(text, @"\w+.BSC");

Console.WriteLine(pattern1.ToString() + pattern2.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.